# How can a SQLAlchemy Class inherit properly despite having a tricky ForeignKey-relationship?

Tags: python, inheritance, sqlalchemy

I implemented joined table inheritance as described in question [SQLAlchemy Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337095/sqlalchemy-inheritance).

There is the following situation: I would like to have a

- **User** which has an `emailaddress`
- **Alias** which assigns an alias - `emailaddress` to another email address

In order to keep the `emailaddress` unique, the idea would be to let both classes inherit from `Emailaddress` using *joined table inheritance*. The examples implements the following classes:

- `Emailaddress`
- `EmailaddressUser(Emailaddress)`
- `EmailaddressAlias(Emailaddress)`

The inheritance enables the following usage:

```
u = EmailaddressUser(name="Testuser", emailaddress="testuser@test.com")
```

=> I don't need to instantiate an `Emailaddress` beforehand - which facilitates the usage.

Unfortunately the same thing doesn't work for `EmailaddressAlias`, although the only difference is the second attribute which is a ForeignKey to the same attribute `emailaddress`. Therefore I need to specify the *inherit_condition*. BUT:

```
  a = EmailaddressAlias (
      real_emailaddress="testuser@test.com",
      alias_emailaddress="tu@test.com"
      )
```

--> Throws an IntegrityError when adding it to the database. See the full example here:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.orm as orm
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Emailaddress(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'emailaddresses'
  emailaddress = sa.Column(sa.String, primary_key=True)
  emailtype = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=False)
  __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': emailtype}


class EmailaddressUser(Emailaddress):
  __tablename__ = 'emailaddress_users'
  __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'user'}
  emailaddress = sa.Column(
      sa.String,
      sa.ForeignKey('emailaddresses.emailaddress'),
      primary_key=True)
  name = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=False)


class EmailaddressAlias(Emailaddress):
  __tablename__ = 'emailaddresses_alias'
  alias_emailaddress = sa.Column(
      sa.String,
      sa.ForeignKey('emailaddresses.emailaddress'),
      primary_key=True)
  real_emailaddress = sa.Column(
      sa.ForeignKey('emailaddresses.emailaddress'),
      nullable=False)
  __mapper_args__ = {
      'polymorphic_identity': 'alias',
      'inherit_condition':Emailaddress.emailaddress==alias_emailaddress}


if __name__ == '__main__':
  engine = sa.create_engine ('sqlite:///email.sqlite', echo=True)
  Base.metadata.bind = engine
  Base.metadata.create_all ()
  Session = orm.sessionmaker (engine)
  session = Session ()
  # add user (works):
  u = EmailaddressUser(name="Testuser", emailaddress="testuser@test.com")
  session.add(u)
  session.commit()
  # --> INSERT INTO emailaddresses (emailaddress, emailtype) VALUES (?, ?)
  # --> ('testuser@test.com', 'user')
  # 'emailaddress' is inserted correctly

  # add alias (throws an IntegrityError):
  a = EmailaddressAlias (
      real_emailaddress="testuser@test.com",
      alias_emailaddress="tu@test.com"
      )
  session.add(a)
  session.commit()
  # --> INSERT INTO emailaddresses (emailtype) VALUES (?)' ('alias',)
  # 'emailaddress' is missing! => IntegrityError
```

Comment: `EmailaddressAlias` has 4 properties, including `emailaddress` and `name` inherited from `Emailaddress`, which you don't pass to constructor of new object. So the exception is expected here. I believe inheriting of `EmailaddressAlias` from `Emailaddress` is a mistake. Try to describe your intention to get better help.

Comment: I added some words in order to clarify my intention. Concening your comment: `name` is not inherited from `Emailaddress`. It is just an attribute from `EmailaddressUser`.

Comment: After some testing, I think it is a bug in SQLAlchemy for the following reason: renaming within `EmailaddressAlias`: `alias_emailaddress` to `emailaddress` (also within at `inherit_condition`) solves the problem. However, `inherit_condition` should allow different naming!

Comment: Here is a good statemend by zzzeek: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/ticket/2344 - Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like there might be a problem be that EmailaddressAlias is inheriting from EmailAddress and not from Base.

I'm not an expert on this, nor have I done this through the mapper_args, but I find using [relationship()](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/relationships.html) to set up the foreign keys works quite well.  For example:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
class EmailaddressAlias(Base):
...
    alias_emailaddress_fk = sa.Column(sa.String, sa.ForeignKey('emailaddresses.emailaddress'))
    alias_emailaddress = relationship(EmailAddress, primaryjoin=alias_emaladdress_fk==EmailAddress.emailaddress)
    real_emailaddress_fk = sa.Column(sa.String, ForeignKey('emailaddresses.emailaddress'))
    real_emailaddress = relationship(EmailAddress,primaryjoin=real_emailaddress_fk==EmailAddress.emailaddress)
```