# Inheritance issue in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, inheritance, sqlalchemy

I need some help with understanding how inheritance works in SQLAlchemy. I've created a base class for a user with some basic functionality. And then some specific users (admin, cooluser, uncooluser). Each one has unique functionality so I decided to use inheritance in SQLAlchemy. The problem is that I need to be able to upgrade a user to cooluser or uncooluser, and downgrade a cooluser to user, at any time,.

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tbl_users'
    __table_args__ = {'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB'}

    user_id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True, unique = True, nullable = False)
    user_name = Column(String(100), nullable = False, unique = True)
    password = Column(String(100), nullable = False)
    user_type = Column('user_type', String(50))
    first_name = Column(String(50), nullable = False)
    last_name = Column(String(50), nullable = False)
    address = Column(String(50), nullable = False)
    city = Column(String(20), nullable = False)
    postal_code = Column(String(10), nullable = False)
    country_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Contries.country_id))

    country = relationship('Country', backref = 'users')

    query = Session.query_property()

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': user_type, 'polymorphic_identity': 'User'}
class CoolUser(User):
    __tablename__ = 'tbl_cool_user'
    __table_args__ = {'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB'}
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'CoolUser'}

    cool_user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.user_id, ondelete = 'CASCADE'), primary_key = True)
    cool_user_balance = Column(Numeric(15, 3))
```

Can I create a CoolUser without creating a new row in 'tbl_users', but use an existing one? Can change some setting so that when a CoolUser gets removed it just removes the entry in 'tbl_cool_user', not 'tbl_user'?

Am I missing the point of inheritance in SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 6):

> Am I missing the point of inheritance in SQLAlchemy?

I think that you misusing the `inheritance` concept in general, and not even in SA implementation specifics.
In a classical `Animal (Cat, Dog (Terier))` type of hierarchy would you ever imagine that a Cat would be *up/down-graded* to a Dog, or even a specific type of a Dog? I don't think so. Also, I can well imagine that some `CoolUser` could also be an `Administrator` at the same time. How will you resolve this type of relationship?

Therefore, for your requirements, inheritance is just not the concept to employ to solve this state-changing model. I would suggest to google for `User-Role` type of relationships and implementations. You would still have to resolve the issue of storing Role-specific data thought.

---

As [@aquavitae](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9719374/99594) mentioned: in SA, you can hack-around and change the `user_type`. But be aware that in this case the following will happen:

- when you load the object from the database, its class will reflect the new type (GOOD)
- when you downgrade the object (from CoolUser to User), the row which corresponds to the CoolUser will **not** be deleted (i think it is BAD, but it might be OK)
- when you upgrade the object (from User to CoolUser), no new row for the CoolUser table will be created, and all your values will be NULL. As such, setting/adding any property that is stored in the non-created row will throw a nice error. And when queries for the specific subclass, you will **not** recieve the object back as the `INNER JOIN` is used to retrieve the object. (BAD)
- in summary, do not change a Cat to a Dog

Comment: +1  I should have put all those caveats in my answer too! In this use case, its probably better to simply query the Users with a filter.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I will have to rethink the entire thing. The reason I thought inheritance would be subtable is because every user (`CoolUser`, `UnCoolUser`, `Admin`) have to log-in, log-out and such. But I guess I was wrong...

Comment: I would suggest you create a separate table for login oriented tasks (call it `User`), and create an hierarchy (like `Person (->CoolPerson, ->UncoolPerson, ->Distributor)` ) for the data model you have, and then have a foreign key on `Person.user_id` (you could even use the same ID value). In this case, the `Administrator` would probably still be a `role` (or just a flag on `User` table) and will be related only to `User` table without knowing anything about `Person` and its descendants.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should be using 'polymorphic_on' and 'polymorphic_identity' in the same table.  What you need to do is create a base table `User` containing all users (i.e. with mapper_args 'polymorphic_on'), then `CoolUser` subclassed from that (with 'polymorphic_identity'):

```
class User(Base):
    ...
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': user_type}

class CoolUser(User):
    ...
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'CoolUser'}
```

Then you can change `user_type` as you like.

Comment: Unless `User` is an abstract class, one needs `polymorhic_identity` also on the `User` table.

Comment: A more detailed example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337095/sqlalchemy-inheritance

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Concrete Table Inheritance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html?highlight=mixing#concrete-table-inheritance). All all common attribute in base table and create 2 different `CoolUser` and `UnCoolUser`.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I'm still confused. How do I change the type of a `User` to `CoolUser`? If I create new `CoolUser`, will it duplicate the `User` in `CoolUser` table?

Comment: Please check the example and try `polymorphic_on`. If you get any error then write that error so we can solve it.

Comment: The database with a certain model already exists and cannot be changed, because there is already another software that connects to it. What I tried to do is make the python code so that it conforms to that model. I will have to rethink the whole thing... I am grateful for the help though.