# What is missing in the TaggedBlogRecord model for inheritance in sqlalchemy for it to work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I am trying modify the [pyramid_blogr](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-blogr/en/latest/basic_models.html) example. The only closest QA thread is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718815/inheritance-issue-in-sqlalchemy) and the [link](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html?highlight=mixing#concrete-table-inheritance) mentioned in that thread. I went through both of them. I am using concrete inheritance, by which I understand that separate tables will be created for each model. Still, when I query records from the second model, I get errors saying that the model do have columns like title or created in TaggedBlogRecord.

Errors

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: ====> entries.created  <======
[SQL: SELECT entrieslanguage.id AS entrieslanguage_id 
FROM entrieslanguage ORDER BY entries.created DESC
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?]
```

The sample code as follows

```
class BlogRecord(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entries'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(Unicode(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    body = Column(UnicodeText, default=u'')
    created = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    edited = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)


class TaggedBlogRecord(BlogRecord):
    __tablename__ = 'taggedentries'
    __mapper_args__ = {'concrete':True}
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tags = Column(Unicode(255))
```

Comment: Did you also update the script that updates the database, then run the script?

Comment: Yes I did. I overlooked what @Michael Merickel answer says. The derived models do not inherit table fields implicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html#concrete-table-inheritance more closely (emphasis added):

> Two critical points should be noted:
>
> **We must define all columns explicitly on each subclass, even those of
> the same name.** A column such as Employee.name here is not copied out
> to the tables mapped by Manager or Engineer for us.
>
> while the Engineer
> and Manager classes are mapped in an inheritance relationship with
> Employee, they still do not include polymorphic loading. Meaning, if
> we query for Employee objects, the manager and engineer tables are not
> queried at all.