# Use of global declarative_base in sqlalchemy table model classes

Tags: python, sql, oop, sqlalchemy, relational-database

I'm learning [`SQLAlchemy`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) and all of the tutorials/related-questions that I'm reading (for example [this tutorial](http://newcoder.io/scrape/part-3/), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534147/python-inheritance-in-sqlalchemy), or [this documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/extensions/declarative.html)) use the paradigm:

```
import sqlalchemy as sqla

DeclarativeBase = sqla.ext.declarative.declarative_base()

class TableModel(DeclarativeBase):
    """SQLAlchemy Model for a Table.
    """
    __tablename__ = "some_table"

    id = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
```

Which relies on the global instance of `DeclarativeBase`.  This seems really strange because if I import this code in numerous other modules/scripts, the instance will be created at some random point in the execution and not entirely well defined.  I guess it just seems non-pythonic or poor-OOP...

Is there a reason why this is totally valid, solid design?  Or is this just the SQLAlchemy-101 version, and there are more robust patterns?

Comment: "I guess it just seems non-pythonic or poor-OOP..." - you would better provide concrete examples to illustrate concrete problems you see in this design. Otherwise it's impossible to answer you question. Because **for me** it seems pythonic and good design ;)

Comment: If it will help to you aestheticism: you can create `meta.py` module, where you can initialize `Engine`, `Session`, `Declarative_Base`. Afrer that, you can import it into you `tablemodel1.py`, `tablemodel2.py` and other. Some more structure.