# How do I extend a SQLAlchemy bound declarative model with extra methods?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

For example, I have a declarative class on module `a`:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    addresses = relationship("Address", backref="user")
```

Now, in module `b` I want to use the mapped entity, but add a method:

```
from a import User

class UserWithExtraMethod(User):
    def name_capitalized(self):
        return self.name.capitalize()

user = UserWithExtraMethod()
print(user.name_capitalized)
```

However, when I run the script, I will get the following error:

```
InvalidRequestError: Multiple classes found for path "User" in the registry of this declarative base. Please use a fully module-qualified path.
```

What have I missed when declaring the user entity? I would like to reuse the previous declared entity.

I am expecting something would be like:

```
class UserWithExtraMethod(User):
    ___magic_reuse_previous_mapper__ = True

    def name_capitalized(self):
        return self.name.capitalize()
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  You do realize the way this is defined in a way that sqlalchemy expects a new table for `UserWithExtraMethod`, resulting in that error message because the `__tablename__` is not defined for that.  Tangentially relevant info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1337871/2904896

Comment: I am not trying to create extra table or do any inheritance. I just want to add an extra method after the entity is created. It want to extend the class without any side effect to the underlying SQL mapper.

Comment: I would like the different modules to have different implementations of the same method.

Comment: Which sqlalchemy version are you using?  I am unable to actually reproduce your issue with either latest version of 0.9 or 0.8.  Alternatively, it's possible your code example alone can't trigger this.

Comment: "Different implementations"?  are you sure you want that?  Are you giving your persistent classes too many responsibilities?  what are some of the different implementations you will need?

Comment: Yes. I want to do a version control on the layer to be exposed. Different implementations are different versions of the same API on the persistent classes. I don't want to put the version number in the method argument. Instead it shall be done by sub classing the original entities to reduce the coupling.

Answer (score 7):

Unless you've got a particular reason to have separate *classes*, you should just write:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    addresses = relationship("Address", backref="user")

    def name_capitalized(self):
        return self.name.capitalize()
```

Since the `name_capitalized` is not special as far as SQLAlchemy is concerned (it's not a `ColumnExpression` or some such), it is completely ignored by the mapper.

Actually, there's an even better way to do this; your version works fine for instances of `User`, but is of no use in sql expressions.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property, hybrid_method
class User(Base):
    # ... body as before

    @hybrid_method
    def name_capitalized(self):
        return self.name.capitalize()

    @name_capitalized.expression
    def name_capitalized(cls):
        # works for postgresql, other databases spell this differently.
        return sqlalchemy.func.initcap(cls.name)
```

which will allow you to do things like:

```
>>> print Query(User).filter(User.name_capitalized() == "Alice")
SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.name AS users_name 
FROM users 
WHERE initcap(users.name) = :initcap_1
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps a little late for this reply. Do you have any *other* relationships setup that are pointing to `User`?

For example, if you have `Address` defined as:

```
class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    address = Column(String(50))
    Users = relationship("User", backref="addresses")
```

when `Address` is trying to resolve to which User within the declarative base to point to, it will find two of them. To verify try `Base._decl_class_registry['User']`. This is similar to [this](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3492/class_registry-issue-with-multiple-classes) topic covered by Michael.

In `./sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/clsregistry.py` there is an example on how to use the fully qualified path. In this case it would be changing the relationship within address from `Users = relationship("User", backref="addresses")` to
`Users = relationship("a.User", backref="addresses")`

Hope this helps point you in the right direction for debugging.

Comment: One thing I am curious is to check when the second User class is being defined. That may help also clear out some of the smoke.

Answer (score 1):

Hacky, but why not just monkey-patch the `User` class for your purpose instead of inheriting from it?

```
# modude b
from a import User

def name_capitalized(self):
    return self.name.capitalize()

User.name_capitalized = name_capitalized    
user = User() # and it has extra-method as well
print(user.name_capitalized)
```

Comment: I am currently doing this, just monkey patching isn't proper. The problem is SQLAlchemy declarative class has a metaclass that create the entity. There seems to be no way to disable invoking the metaclass from creating it again.

Answer (score 1):

This may not work for you. I had a similar issue. I ended up passing an instance of User to UserWithExtraMethod during instantiation

```
class UserWithExtraMethod(object):
    def __init__(self, user):
        self.user = user

    def name_capitalized(self):
        return self.user.name.capitalize()
```

Hope this helps